# summary function doesn't print Error Measures and accuracy function prints error

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

summary function in R doesn't print the Error Measure values and accuracy function throws error. I don't understand why. Anyone please help me to understand.

Below is the error code:

```
> summary(forecast1)
     Length Class Mode  
pred 12     ts    numeric
se   12     ts    numeric
> accuracy(forecast1)
Error in accuracy.default(forecast1) :
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.
```

Comment: I think you need to change the Class from ts

Comment: Can I know to which class I need to change from ts to??